# how to make WordPress sidebar with upload images ability

Tags: wordpress, image, sidebar

I need to make part of my WordPress sidebar with ability of uploading images, something like this: http://prntscr.com/69h2fp
I need to could upload and give the link to images from admin panel without limitation, my mean is i need to be able to upload images in there as i need not only 2,3 or 10 images max.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These appear to be two possible solutions:

Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-widget/

Code it yourself: http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-upload-media-library-widgets